# DB2 LOAD / IMPORT, Load1 flat file into multiple tables

Tags: db2, db2-luw, bulk-load

Need to load a flat file into 4 different tables (i.e 1 row in flat file goes into 4 different tables). These 4 different tables maintain one common key to identify the association. How do I load such data using DB2 load/import. Does DB2 load / import provide such capability? Hard part is maintaining the association.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `LOAD` nor `IMPORT` support loading data into multiple tables at once. You will have to make four files out of your one file, making sure each one contains your common key, and load them separately.

Comment: They don't have to be separate files, if all the values are flattened, the LOAD/IMPORT can select columns using `METHOD N() or P()`